# Passing values to a javascript code from ASP.NET/C# for google map application

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I'm going to make a web application in asp.net/C# and I'm going to use interactive google maps in that project. I want to get coordinates from a SQL Server database and mark them on the google map using javascript code. I'm following this tutorial.

http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/Working-with-Google-Maps-API-in-ASPNET.aspx

I'm stuck here.
Javascript code:

```
 var lat = <asp:Literal ID="ltrLat" runat="server" />;
            var lng = <asp:Literal ID="ltrLng" runat="server" />;

            var center = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
```

C#code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

Literal ltrLat = (Literal)FindControl("ltrLat");
Literal ltrLng = (Literal)FindControl("ltrLng");

ltrLat.Text = "51";
ltrLng.Text = "0";
```

}

I get the following error:
Null Reference Exception was unhandled by the user.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong code:

```
var lat = <asp:Literal ID="ltrLat" runat="server" />;
var lng = <asp:Literal ID="ltrLng" runat="server" />;
```

you should get value of the control not control itself:

```
var lat = document.getElementById("<%=hdnLat.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
var lng = document.getElementById("<%=hdnLng.ClientID %>").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could just get rid from the error just now, by removing :                                                  Literal ltrLat = (Literal)FindControl("ltrLat");
Literal ltrLng = (Literal)FindControl("ltrLng");                                                                 But I don't know whether it's the correct way. As you say I get the code underlined in the begining of the statement. But that doesn't throw an error. I would be glad if you can show me the correct way.